# How can I parse a string and create a dynamic bag out of it?

Tags: kql, azure-data-explorer

Consider the following situation, where I have a column `Column1` that can contain multiple key/value pairs in the form of `key1=value1, key2=value2, ...`.

However, I don't know the name of the keys beforehand, nor do I know the amount of kv-pairs contained.

What I need to achieve is parsing these kv-pairs and store them in a bag as separate kv pairs. For example `Column1: 'key1=value1, key2=value2'` should become `Bag1: { "Key1": "Value1", "Key2": "Value2" }`

I am aware of the `parse` operator. Unfortunately, the key names need to be known (and static) beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code to get the required output:

```sql
datatable(Column1:string)
[
    'key1=value1, key2=value2, key3=value3',
    'keyA=valueA, keyB=valueB',
    'keyX=valueX',
]
| extend KeyValuePairs = split(Column1, ", ")
| mv-expand KeyValuePairs
| extend KeyValue = split(KeyValuePairs, "=")
| summarize Bag = make_bag(pack(tostring(KeyValue[0]), tostring(KeyValue[1])))
```

**Output:**
[image]